# Limit line length in ansible's console output

Tags: console, formatting, ansible

When running `ansible-playbook` in a console, one could resize the console window to limit the line-length of the console output. ansible uses the `fcntl.ioctl` to get `TIOCGWINSZ`, when it finds a tty `os.isatty(0)` eg: (copied from /ansible/utils/display.py)

```
def _set_column_width(self):
    if os.isatty(0):
        tty_size = unpack('HHHH',
                       fcntl.ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, pack('HHHH', 0, 0, 0, 0)))[1]
    else:
        tty_size = 0
    self.columns = max(79, tty_size - 1)
```

Tools like `man` provide an environment variable `MANWIDTH` to provide this, without resizing the console window.

How can i resize the console output without resizing the console window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check in ansilbes `os.isatty(0)` checks if stdin is open, so the solution was to just redirect stdin, when invoking the command eg, i did:

`ansible-playbook -v -i dev --check --diff playbook.yml 0</dev/null`

NOTE: This does not limit the output of the modules, but that's another story, i guess.

EDIT: As can be seen in the function `_set_column_width` the output defaults to 79 char line length, when there is no tty (stdin is closed).